# Get the selected value in jquery autocomplete on blur function

Tags: jquery, html, css, autocomplete

I want to have auto complete functionality, where the text-box should get populated with the value list as a first item when there is an blur event.

I would like to have the functionality same as implemented in this link [link](http://www.redbus.in/)

[image]

I have the code below, which populates on tab and enter key, but dont know how to achieve same functionality on blur event.

```
$( "#statelist" ).autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    source: states,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        stateid = (ui.item.lable);
        $("#stateid").val(stateid);
    }
});
```

EDIT :-
user enters a text lets us say type "che" and without pressing tab or enter key, user moves his control to next textbox, in this scenario I want the first list item to populated automatically in the textbox.

Comment: Are you using jQueryUI?

Comment: yes i do use jquery ui

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can send a enter key on blur event.

```
     $( "#statelist" ).blur(function(){
         var keyEvent = $.Event("keydown");
         keyEvent.keyCode = $.ui.keyCode.ENTER;
         $(this).trigger(keyEvent);
     }).autocomplete({
         autoFocus: true,
         source: states,
         // ...
     });
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/trSdL/4/

And here is a similar question.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15466735/1670643

Comment: This answer does not working mate, plus it is causing so many alerts hanging up the page :S

Comment: @pappu_kutty Sorry, I posted the wrong fiddle link. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Aditya Is `plus it is causing so many alerts hanging up the page` meaning the `event propagation`?
If so , you can stop this event propagation. See http://jsfiddle.net/trSdL/5/

Comment: @andyf this is working as i expected, but one issue i found, let us say i entered "a" and items listed in dropdown i hover over list itmes and moved away from the list, in this case none of the items selected and autocomplete doesnt work :)

Comment: @andyf How are you fetching the selected data object?

Comment: @pappu_kutty Yes i found this issue too. I think it is a common problem for jQueryUI. And I think jQueryUI should provide a option for keeping stay on the first selection just like http://www.redbus.in/, or keeping stay on other selection when mouse over. I will try to find out the solution for this issue. Please let me know if you find the answer too. Thanks.

Comment: @andyf you are correct, it seems to be an issue with jquery ui as discussed here https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-hover-problem-autocomplete-combobox.

Comment: @pappu_kutty Also a discussion on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586399/jquery-autocomplete-loses-selection-on-mouse-out . But NO solution now :(

Answer (score 5):

This is the Working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/draditya91/AR6jK/4/)

Use  [`autoFocus: true`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-autoFocus) option available for the autocomplete, and then put the first result obtained into your input box on the `blur` event,simple.

### JS :

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    autoFocus: true,
    selectFirst: true,
    open: function(event, ui) { if(select) select=false; },
    select: function(event, ui) { select=true; }
}).blur(function(){
    if(!select)
    {
        $("#tags").val($('ul.ui-autocomplete li:first a').text());
    }
});
```

If you have two autocomplete : [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/draditya91/6hfyb/2/)

If you have an associative array data:
Eg:

```
var availableTags = [
    {'label': 'dog', 'value':1},
    { 'label' : 'cat' , 'value':2} ,
    {'label': 'ant', 'value':3},
    {'label': 'bat', 'value':4},
    {'label': 'deer', 'value':5},
    {'label': 'elephant', 'value':6},
    {'label': 'frog', 'value':7},
    {'label': 'giraffe', 'value':8},
    {'label': 'snake', 'value':9}
 ];
```

**Use:**

`ui.item.label` gives the label , `ui.item.value` gives the corresponding value : [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/draditya91/AR6jK/5/)

```
select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#tags').val(ui.item.label); //shows label in autocomplete
        select=true;
        return false;
    }
```

You can also access `data.autocomplete.selectedItem` in your `change` event of autocomplete to get the selected autocomplete object ,[**See here**](http://jsfiddle.net/draditya91/AR6jK/7/)

```
 change:function(event,ui){  
    if(!select)
    {
       $('ul.ui-autocomplete li:first a').trigger('click');
    }
    var data=$.data(this);//Get plugin data for 'this'
    console.log(data.autocomplete.selectedItem);
}
```

Comment: The seletor `$('ul.ui-autocomplete li:first a')` not work while there are multi `autocomplete` tags. Simply fork from your DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/6hfyb/

Comment: Then you will have to make a a small change  `$("#tags2").val($('ul.ui-autocomplete:eq(1) li:first a').text());` ,see here : **jsfiddle.net/draditya91/6hfyb/2**

Comment: @Aditya how to get array objects text and value, let us say var args=[name:dog, val:1; name:cat, val:2; name:rat, val:3]

Comment: @Aditya , select function is not called on blur event, so i need to get item data inside blur , thanks

Comment: @Aditya I don't think using selector by index (`:eq(N)`) is a good idea. In some case when `autocomplete` tags are dynamically created, it's difficult to get the index number.

Comment: @Aditya what is the plugin i need to add, this is not working,getting Cannot read property 'selectedItem' of undefined

Comment: @pappu_kutty Load jquery UI 1.9.2 and that would solve the issue i think :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you are missing:

```
change: function( event, ui ) {}
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

*untested

```
$( "#statelist" ).autocomplete({
                            change: function( event, ui ) {}
                            autoFocus: true,
                            source: states,
                            select: function (event, ui) {
                                    stateid = (ui.item.lable);
                                    $("#stateid").val(stateid);
                           },
                        }
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

here i leave you a function already working for what you need getting the value on blur

I paste part of the code here

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    open: function(event, ui) { disable=true; },
    close: function(event, ui) { 
        disable=false; $(this).focus(); }
}).blur(function(){
    if(!disable){
        alert($(this).val());
    }
});
```

[JsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/alecellis1985/AR6jK/)

Answer (score 2):

Check this [**`Fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/AR6jK/1/) .. This might helps you ...

**Script**

```
$( "#from" ).autocomplete({
    source: fromCity,
    select: function(event, ui) { 
        $( "#from" ).blur();        
        $( "#to" ).focus();
    }
});   
$( "#to" ).autocomplete({
    source: toCity
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. It should work for you:

```
$('#statelist').autocomplete({
source: states,
autoFocus: true,
selectFirst: true,

open: function(event, ui) { if(select) select=false; },
    select: function(event, ui) { select=true; },

})

.live("blur", function(event) {
var get_val = $('ul.ui-autocomplete li:first a').text();

$('#stateid').val(get_val);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Tested solution**
It will force select first item if there is none
Will work also when you first search in autocomplete
and click over somewhere without even focusing on item list

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/killwithme/ke8osq27/

```
var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
   "BASIC",
   "C",
   "C++",
];

$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    autoFocus: true,
    selectFirst: true,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#tags").val(ui.item.value);
        $("#tags-span").text(ui.item.value);
    }
}).on('autocompletechange', function() {
    if ($(this).data('ui-autocomplete').selectedItem === null) {
    //this will trigger your select automatically so it will handle other custom override you did for select
        $(this).data('ui-autocomplete').menu.element.children('li:first').children('a').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue described by @pappu_kutty in comment section of marked answer

> "@andyf this is working as i expected, but one issue i found, let us say i entered "a" and items listed in dropdown i hover over list itmes and moved away from the list, in this case none of the items selected and autocomplete doesnt work :) – pappu_kutty"

add below code to autocomplete change event. It basically prevents any invalid choice in the autocomplete box.

```
change: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.item == null) {
                    $(this).val('');
                    $(this).focus();
                    return;
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple autocompletes using @Aditya answer.
After some researches the best I found has been to apply classes at the open method on the dropdown and using them to match the right dropdown.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ac1fkr5w/2/

Code:

```
var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"];

var select = false;

$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    autoFocus: true,
    selectFirst: true,
    open: function(event, ui) {
    //Adding class
    $(this).data("uiAutocomplete").menu.element.addClass("tags");
    if(select) select=false; },
    select: function(event, ui) { select=true; }
}).blur(function(){
    if(!select)
    {
    //Using class to match the right ul
        $("#tags").val($('ul.tags li:first a').text());
    }
}); 


$("#tags2").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    autoFocus: true,
    selectFirst: true,
    open: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).data("uiAutocomplete").menu.element.addClass("tags2");
    if(select) select=false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) { select=true; }
}).blur(function(){
    if(!select)
    {
        $("#tags2").val($('ul.tags2 li:first a').text());
    }
});
```