# Autocomplete won't work if focus is not in textfield

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

Guys I am using autocomplete (remote call) of Jquery UI [enter link description here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) and it works fine when text field is in focus, and suppose before getting the response user clicks anywhere outside then autocomplete list never shows up, we again need to bring the focus to that text field and type again. Is there any way to show autocomplete list even after typing something if user remove the focus from that text field?

Comment: I think you may be looking for something like **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22746493/1730461)**

Comment: No not this one, here user is asking to autopopulate the textbox but I want to open the autocomplete list even if user moved to next field or clicked anywhere in screen...